# Tensorflow ends up in an infinite loop

Tags: tensorflow

This tensorflow code is not responding, and i can't figure out why. Please help!

```
import tensorflow as tf
#reading the file
with tf.name_scope ('File_reading') as scope:
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["forestfires.csv.digested"])
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults = [[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]
    #13 decoded
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13 = tf.decode_csv(
        value, record_defaults=record_defaults) 


    #12 is feture, and the 13th is the training data
    features = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12],name='data_input')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Start populating the filename queue.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        for i in range(517):
            # Retrieve a single instance:
            example, label = sess.run([features, col13])

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
with tf.name_scope ('network') as scope:
    W1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([12, 8]), name='W1')
    b1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([8]), name="b1")
    h1=tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(features,0), W1),b1, name='hidden_layer')
    W2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([8, 1]), name='W2')
    b2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="b2")
    output=tf.add(tf.matmul(h1, W2),b2, name='output_layer')
error=tf.add(output,-col13, name='error')
#training
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(error)
#graphing the output
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('some directory', sess.graph)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #init
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print ("\n\n\n\n\n\nTRAINING STARTED\n\n\n\n\n\n")
    print('test1')
    sess.run(error) #this statement causes an infinite loop
    print ('test2')
file_writer.close()
```

the code runs, and prints 'test1', but then it does nothing, not even responds to ctrl+c. I've tried to look-up the problem, but either my google skills aren't good enough, or it is not on the internet. 
system: win10
        geforce 960M
        python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you constructed the network, intellectually does not make sens. If you need to read 517 steps from your TextLineReader use the function read_up_to and supply the value of 517 rather than using separate sessions. In the way you constructed the graph, there doesn't seem to be a neat connection between the input reader and the rest of the graph.

My suggestion:

```
# define graph which includes the input queue
def model(...):
...
  return error, metrics

with tf.Graph.as_default():
  error, metrics = model(...)

  with tf.Session():
    # Start Coordinator
    # Initialise global vars
    # Start queue runners
    # model_error, model_metrics = sess.run([error, metrics])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (for this bug), it wasn't an infinite loop, it just waited for input data. For some reason, if I paste the upper 'with tf.Session() as sess:' block (without the with part) into the top of the lower with block, it runs nicely. (It may be possible, that there are some other coding errors, because i've changed a few things since then.)